# How to dynamically change List items for the ListView in Android?

Tags: java, android, listview

Here's my data structure class:

```
public class FirstAidSteps implements Parcelable {
    //These are the fields
    private final String stepName;
    private final ArrayList<String> steps;
    .
    .
    .
}
```

Here's the adapter I've written:

```
public class StepsAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<FirstAidSteps> {
    public StepsAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<FirstAidSteps> users) {
    super(context, 0, users);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        FirstAidSteps steps = getItem(position);

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
        }

        TextView stepName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.step_heading);
        stepName.setText(steps.getStepName());

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

Here's the XML for List Item:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/step_heading"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:textSize="25sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

I want to add the contents of ArrayList *steps* to the ListView. And I can't predefine the XML for *steps* because they can have any size.

I want the output something like below:

```
 ___________________
| StepName          |
|   Step            |
|   Step            |
|-------------------|
| StepName          |
|   Step            |
|-------------------|
| StepName          |
|___________________|
```

So how to do this?

Comment: where you are using array list?

Comment: add array list in list using your adapter.. and when ever you want to change the value at any point just change the value in array list at any X position. and use notifyDatasetchange method to see changes in list view

Comment: @Mustanser Iqbal I've updated the question with the desired output.

Comment: ok let me add answer.

Comment: your step name will always be in list?

Comment: and only steps will varies right?

Comment: @Mustanser Iqbal Yeah steps vary but stepName is always there.

Comment: sorry i was on lunch break.. i have added the answer you can check..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the number of steps is fairly small, I usually use a LinearLayout here, and add the necessary views.

To do this, you simply need to add a LinearLayout to your item view to contain the steps.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/step_heading"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:textSize="25sp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/steps"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Then you add steps to your item view via the adapter.  Make sure you clear the previous steps in the view (also making sure you use the ViewHolder pattern).

```
public class StepsAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<FirstAidSteps> {

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View v = convertView;
        ViewHolder holder;
        if (v == null) {
            v = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.stepName = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.step_heading);
            holder.steps = (LinearLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.steps);
            v.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) v.getTag();
        }

        final FirstAidSteps steps = getItem(position);
        holder.stepName.setText(steps.getStepName());

        holder.steps.removeAllViews();
        for (String step : steps.getSteps()) {
            holder.steps.addView(createStepView(step));
        }

        return v;
    }

    private static class ViewHolder {
        TextView stepName;
        LinearLayout steps;
    }
}
```

In this case, `createStepView()` is an exercise for the reader.

Depending on your layout and possible number of steps, this may not be the best solution for you. If you will potentially have a lot of steps you may want to look into some sort of recycler view, or other recycling container.

Answer (score 0):

cahnge your xml file to this

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/step_heading"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:textSize="25sp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/steps"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

change steps to this

```
private final ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> steps;
private final ArrayList<String> stepsName;
```

and in adapter

```
public StepsAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> steps, ArrayList<String> stepsName) {
super(context, 0, steps, stepsName);
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
    }

    TextView stepName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.step_heading);
    LinearLayout mLinearLayout = (LinearLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.steps);
    stepName.setText(stepsName.get(position));

    mLinearLayout.removeAllViews();

    ArrayList<String> single_step= steps.get(position);

    if(single_step.size() > 0){

        for (int size =0; size <single_step.size(); size++) {

                TextView text = new TextView(this);
                text.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
                            LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                            LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
                text.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
                text.setPadding(5, 2, 5, 2);
                text.setText(single_step.get(size));
                mLinearLayout.addView(text);

        }
    }
    return convertView;
}
```